# Why can't I put this tuple ([0, 2], [3, 4]) into a set in Python?

Tags: python

Why can't I put this tuple `([0, 2], [3, 4])` into a set in Python?

I got the following error when I tried:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Please update your question with your code and the full error traceback.

Comment: Because it contains lists, which aren't hashable.

Comment: Set elements can't be lists.

Comment: because set can only contains hashable type. List can't be hashed. So you can't create tuple with list. Same with set and dict.

Answer (score 3):

Attempting to put a tuple inside a set or a dict's keys requires all of the tuple's values to be hashable (for internal comparison).

Since lists are mutable, and the same object can change, it's impossible to hash and later compare, and therefore hashing is completely blocked.

Comment: Put another way, even though the tuple is immutable (which might make it appear as though it should be allowed in a set), if the elements of the tuple are mutable (like a list) then it's not allowed in a set because it can be modified after being added into the set.